# css ie7 adding extra space between lines

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I've just deployed a site and coming up with a number of ie7 css issues which I suppose I should have anticipated. I'm having trouble debugging in a virtual version of IE7, I have installed debugBar and IETester but I can't visually see the padding or margins on the elements as you can with say Chrome or Firebug...

SO first part of my question - are they tools I can use in IE7 that will help debug css?

The second part relates to an element that features on two different pages. The element is a UL which renders with extra space within the elements, on the other page it renders correctly.

The html is:

```
  <div id="nextSevenEvents">
  <ul id="nextSevenEventseventList">
    <li>
      <div class="dateEntry last span-6 last borderTop">  
        <div class="whatsOnDate last span-2 "> Fri 20 Apr</div>
        <div class="whatsOnTitle span-4 last">Ladies v Royal (Away) FR</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="dateEntry last span-6 last ">  
        <div class="whatsOnDate last span-2 "> &nbsp;</div>
        <div class="whatsOnTitle span-4 last">Terry on hols</div>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

The css for these is:

```
   #div-whatson ul {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 5px 0 0;
     margin: 0;
   }
   .dateEntry {
     padding: 5px 0 0 0;
   }
   .whatsOnDate {
     font-size: 0.8em;
     line-height: 1em;
   }
     .whatsOnTitle {
     font-size: 0.9em;
     line-height: 1em;
   }
```

What am I missing here?

My site is based around blueprint

Thanks

update: #div=whatson is a parent element and has some other elements within it (left it out otherwise my code would have gone on and on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add this to your CSS:

```
#div-whatson ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a parent element with id 'div-whatson' wrapping the list? Have you set an explicit size for body font-size as there may be issues arising from inheritance.

A tool which is pretty handy when debugging IE versions is the built-in Developer Tools in IE9 (F12 to bring it up). From here you can change the versions of IE. I wouldn't count on this being 100% accurate but it is a useful tool.

Comment: Hi - yes it's a container of sorts. I included the css as it directly affects the UL element. I left the div-whatson out of the html here as it's got loads of other bits in it. I'll check out the ie9 tools - thank you for the pointer

Comment: I've now learned something - thank you for your tip with ie9 - brilliant!